# Get Username of Currently interacting User in WCF both Rest Endpoint and MVC3 with Windows Authentication

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, wcf, web-services, rest, windows-authentication

In an MVC3 project that I'm working on we're trying to move a lot of our logic that is currently in the controllers into a service layer and expose it as a REST Service in WCF.

So in our Global.asax we create a Service Route like so:

```
RouteTable.Routes.Add(new ServiceRoute
    ("Exampleservice", new WebServiceHostFactory(), typeof(ExampleService)));
```

and our controllers access the service something like this:

```
public class ExampleController : Controller {
    private IExampleService service;

    public ExampleController() {
        this.service = new ExampleService();
    } 

    public ActionResult Index() {
         var results = service.GetAll();
         return View(results);
    }
}
```

The main point here being that we use the service class directly (without making requests over the network with an HttpClient).

Our website uses Windows Authentication (it's an intranet site) and we would like to keep it that way. My Question is, is there a way that I can get the User's Identity in the service class that will work both for how we have the Controllers using the service, and the way that WCF uses the service?

For example:

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface IExampleService
{
    [WebGet(UriTemplate = "/")]
    List<Results> GetAll();
}

public class ExampleService : IExampleService
{
     List<Results> GetAll() {
         // Get User Name Here
         // In ASP.Net I would use User.Identity.Name
         // If I was just worrying about the the REST service I would use
         // ServiceSecurityContext.Current.WindowsIdentity.Name
     }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The instruction suggested by @Ryand.Johnson is correct. The point here is that the controller do not send any credentials to the web service because it run under the asp.net user indentity not the identity of the currently loggedd user. The only way to pass the identity to the proxy is by embedding the call to the web service within an impersonation context this way:

```
using (WindowsImpersonationContext impersonatedUser = (User.Identity as System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity).Impersonate()){ 
     //your proxy call here  }
```

If still this way you get null you have to set manually the default credentials to your proxy

Comment: I'm not using a proxy. Does this still work then (haven't had an opportunity to try it yet)? In my example using your answer, my code would for the method call would look like this : ` using (WindowsImpersonationContext impersonatedUser = (User.Identity as System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity).Impersonate()){ var results = service.GetAll(); return View(results); } ` correct? And the code in the Example Service would just always use OperationContext.Current.ServiceSecurityContext.WindowsIdentity.Name to get the Username?

Comment: Ye this is the way I suggested. However, once you have done impersonation you need a way to pass the current user credentials to the web serviuce to be called. If service is a proxy created automatically by Visual Studio this is easy...but you said it is not...so you have to find a way to make service send the credentials to the web service.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, in the service security context...

`OperationContext.Current.ServiceSecurityContext.WindowsIdentity.Name`

Comment: OperationContext.Current comes back null when the request comes through the controller. So does ServiceSecurityContext.Current.

Comment: What happens when you add the operationcontract attribute to the interface's GetAll()  
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.operationcontext.aspx

Comment: It still comes back null. I tried with both OperationContext and ServiceSecurityContext.